# Flask - allowing users into a group of projects, based on project being a variable and an @app.route id

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I am using flask-security. I would like to set up `@roles_accepted` with a variable based upon the app route.

For example, if `_id = Lon_2020` the `@roles_accepted` would allow `Lon`. This would grant certain users to projects, but not others, based on the _id.

```
@app.route('/<string:_id>')
@app.route('/<string:_id>/')
@roles_accepted('admin',_id[:3])
def home(_id):
    return redirect(url_for('tb',_id=_id))
```

At the moment, this causes an error, because _id is not defined. The roles_accepted relies on the _id data.

If this is not possible, would you mind letting me know a better way of allowing certain users into certain projects. e.g.

```
Lon_2019
Lon_2020
Lon_2021
Par_2019
Par_2020
Par_2021
Ber_2018
Ber_2019

where the identified is the first 3 characters 'Lon','Par','Ber'
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `@roles_accepted` decorator with another decorator! In the code below the variable name to extract the role is being passed in the outer decorator although it could be hard-coded.

```
def roles_accepted_from_route(variable_name):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            _variable = kwargs.get(variable_name, None)
            if _variable:
                print(_variable, _variable[:3])

                @roles_accepted('admin', _variable[:3])
                def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                    print(f'roles_accepted returned True, variable: {_variable[:3]}')
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                return inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

And use as follows:

```
@app.route('/<string:_id>')
@roles_accepted_from_route(variable_name='_id')
def some_route(_id):
    return f'Route Variable: {_id}'
```

Single file example below, there is little error checking. A user with `email`: 'fred@example.net', `password`: 'password' with role 'LON' is created on the first Flask request.

```
from functools import wraps
from flask import Flask
from flask_security import roles_accepted
from flask_security.utils import hash_password
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, UserMixin, RoleMixin, current_user

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'super-secret'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///test.db3'
app.config['SECURITY_PASSWORD_SALT'] = '5ce39dc7add2284076de45b923d74dd00a052117cdf0ab900548565681e56fce'


# Create database connection object
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# Define models
roles_users = db.Table('roles_users',
        db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
        db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id')))


class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))


# Setup Flask-Security
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)
security = Security(app, user_datastore)


# Create a user to test with
@app.before_first_request
def create_user():
    db.drop_all()
    db.create_all()
    _lon_role = user_datastore.create_role(name='LON')
    _user = user_datastore.create_user(email='fred@example.net', password=hash_password('password'))
    user_datastore.add_role_to_user(_user, _lon_role)
    db.session.commit()


def roles_accepted_from_route(variable_name):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            _variable = kwargs.get(variable_name, None)
            if _variable:
                print(_variable, _variable[:3])

                @roles_accepted('admin', _variable[:3])
                def inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
                    print(f'roles_accepted returned True, variable: {_variable[:3]}')
                    return func(*args, **kwargs)
                return inner_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator


@app.route('/')
def home():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return f'You are logged in as : {current_user.email} and have roles: {",".join([r.name for r in current_user.roles])}'
    else:
        return f'<a href="/login">Login</a>'


@app.route('/<string:_id>')
@roles_accepted_from_route(variable_name='_id')
def some_route(_id):
    return f'Route Variable: {_id}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the documentation from `Flask-Security` library for `roles_accepted` decorator.

flask_security.decorators.roles_accepted(*roles): 
    Decorator which specifies that a user must have at least one of the specified roles. Example:

```
@app.route('/create_post')
@roles_accepted('editor', 'author')
def create_post():
    return 'Create Post'
```

In order to use this decorator, you need to first create the roles in your role table, and user your model and role model needs to follow the certain format so that `Flask-Security` library can recognize existing roles.

**Model Example**

```
# association table between user and role
roles_users = db.Table(
'roles_users',
db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
)

# role table
class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):

    __tablename__ = 'role'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30), unique=True)

# user table
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
```

Once you've specified the mode such as above, then you create the `role` by inserting into `role` table. Once you create `editor` and `author` roles like shown above in the view, when the user with either `editor` or `author` role come in to `/create_post` view, it will be able to control the access-control based on roles.

If you are getting the ID of `user` or `role` from above, and want to perform access-control based on that (which I think it is unnecessary) because `Flask-Security` has `current_user` variable where you can parse out all information about that user without you manually making the query). 
You will have to first make the query using the ID to `user` or `role` table, then based on that, you will either throw `403` or allow the content to return which then you won't require to have your own `@roles_accepted('editor', 'author')`, because you are doing that manually.

Comment: The issue is that I have hundreds of webpages created by one app route. i.e. there are over 300 pages generated by this app route: @app.route('/<string:_id>'), because there are over 300 ids. However there are almost ‘subroles’ inside the list of id’s, so I cant define one role for the app route. I need a way of returning _id[:3] before @the app.route

Comment: Then I think you'd be better off just checking the roles manually without using the flask-security. You can easily do them when the request is received, just check the prefix of the id and decide whether to 403 or return correct result.

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this - don't use the decorator - in your app.route - have the first couple lines calculate the 'role' then call the decorator directly such as:

```
@app.route("/createpost")
@auth_required()
def createpost():
  /// figure out what role based on current_user or whatever
  return roles_required("author")(domyview)()

def domyview():
    // Actual code for endpoint here.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution which is working, but isn’t perfect. Based on @Jessi suggestion of 403 abort:

```
def check_user(c_id):
    if current_user.has_role('admin'):
        current = c_id
    to_check = ['Lon','Par’,’Ber'] #manual inserton of roles from db, could use sqlalchemy to query db instead?
    for n in to_check:
        if current_user.has_role(n):
            current = n
    if c_id == current:
        return True

@app.route('/<string:_id>')
@app.route('/<string:_id>/')
def home(_id):
    c_id = _id[:3])
    if check_user(c_id):
        return redirect(url_for('tb',_id=_id))
    else:
        return abort(403)
```